# How can I to do `git reset --soft <some-commit>` bypassing commits with merge?

Tags: git, git-reset

I have two branches - `master` and `some`:

```
  C2---M3---C4---C5 some
 /    /
C1---C3---C6---C7 master
```

Where `C1`, `C2`... - it's commits and `M3` - merge commit `C3`.

I want to do:

```
git checkout some
git reset --soft C1
```

But I want to get around the merge commit `M3`.

How can I to do this?

Comment: What does your final diagram look like?  I'm not sure this will work as you expect given that there is a merge commit.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, as a result, I want to see the work done in branch `some`, but without commit.

Comment: @ktretyak You do want changes from the commits `C2`, `C4` and `C5`, but not from the merge `M3`, don't you?

Comment: @phd, yes, your are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the cherry-picking approach, but another way would be:

```
git checkout some
git rebase --interactive --preserve-merges C2
```

...then edit the presented picklist, changing the `pick` to `drop` at the front of the line for the merge commit M3.  You'll end up with `C5->C4->C2` as the set of commits on `some` that aren't also in `master`.

Answer (score 2):

So you want changes from the commits `C2`, `C4` and `C5`, but not from the merge `M3`. I'd do that with a new branch:

```
# Create a new branch started at C1
git checkout -b some-new C1

# Cherry-pick commits
git cherry-pick C2 C4 C5

# Delete the old branch and rename the new
git branch -D some
git branch -m some
```

Answer (score 2):

First, let's note that commits are (entirely) read-only and (mostly) permanent.  Given a commit graph fragment like this one:

```
  C2---M3---C4---C5  <-- some
 /    /
C1---C3---C6---C7  <-- master
```

the no matter what `reset`-ing we do, these same commits will continue to exist, at least for a while.  If we add a saving name (branch or tag name) that also points to commit `C5`, then whatever we do to the name `some`, we will still be able to name commits `C5`, `C4`, `M3`, and `C2`.

Second, remember that each commit stores a complete, independent snapshot.  That includes merge commit `M3`.  We can turn a merge commit into a set of changes by running `git diff` to compare the contents of the snapshot to the contents of the commit's parent—but for a merge commit, which has *two* parents, we have to pick one of the two parents.

Third, since you mention `git reset --soft`, let's note that, separate and apart from commits, Git gives us a *work-tree* in which we do our actual work (and can view commits), and an *index*—also called the *staging area* or the *cache*—that we use to build up each commit before we make it.  If we run:

```
git checkout some
```

Git will fill the index and work-tree from the contents of the commit to which the name `some` currently points, i.e., `C5`, and attach our `HEAD` to the name `some`.  Let's attach a second name, `tmp`, at this point, using `git branch tmp`:

```
  C2---M3---C4---C5  <-- some (HEAD), tmp
 /    /
C1---C3---C6---C7  <-- master
```

Running `git reset --soft <hash-of-C1>` at this point will make the name `some` point to commit `C1` while leaving our index and work-tree unchanged.  That is, the index and work-tree contents will continue to match those of `C5`:

```
  C2---M3---C4---C5  <-- tmp
 /    /
C1---C3---C6---C7  <-- master
 .
  ... <-------------- some (HEAD)
```

If we make a new commit now, by running `git commit`, we get a new commit `C8` whose contents match those of `C5`.  This is because the new commit is made from the contents of the index, which match the contents of `C5`.  The parent of `C8` will be `C1`, however, giving us:

```
  C2---M3---C4---C5  <-- tmp
 /    /
C1---C3---C6---C7  <-- master
 \
  C8  <-------------- some (HEAD)
```

after which `git diff some tmp` will show no difference at all.

You mention in comments that what you want, in the index or perhaps as new commit `C8`, is *content* that would be achieved by cherry-picking `C2`, `C4`, and `C5` atop commit `C1`.  You cannot get this with `git reset` alone.

#### Build by cherry-picking

The most straightforward way to get this is to set a branch name to point to commit `C1` and, at the same time, set up the index and work-tree to match `C1`:

```
git checkout -b new <hash-of-C1>
```

and then use `git cherry-pick`, optionally with `-n`, as in [phd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49365499/1256452), which went in as I was typing this in.  You could also use `git reset --hard`, rather than `git reset --soft`, to move `some` to point to `C1` while retaining a name for commit `C5` (as in the above diagrams using `tmp`).  Then the *name* of the new branch you build, by cherry-picking the three desired commits, would be `some`.

#### Build by reverting

Last, you can, if you like, try to construct your new commit by a *subtractive* process.  This can be a bit error prone as it depends on what went into merge `M3`,<sup>1</sup> but it works like this:

- We know that `C5` is, in effect, `C1`, plus `C2`-as-changeset, plus `C1`-vs-`C3` as changeset-via-merge, plus `C4`-as-changeset, plus `C5`-as-changeset.
- We can compute `C1`-vs-`C3` directly, by `git diff`-ing them.
- Better: we can compute `C1-vs-C3` *indirectly*, by `git diff`ing `C2` vs `M3`.  This will handle certain cases of duplication, where `C1`-vs-`C3` has the *same* changes as `C1`-vs-`C2`, so that they were not doubly-included in `C2`-vs-`M3`.
- We can (at least try to) *reverse-apply* any patch we like at any time.  That is, having turned a commit into a changeset (by comparing against a parent), instead of copying those changes into some commit that *doesn't* have them, we can *undo* those changes in some commit that *does* have them.  The command to do this is `git revert`.

Suppose, then, we check out commit `some` as before so that we have just the initial setup:

```
  C2---M3---C4---C5  <-- some (HEAD)
 /    /
C1---C3---C6---C7  <-- master
```

Now we run `git revert -m 1 <hash-of-M3>`.  This tells Git to diff `C2` vs `M3` to see what changed.<sup>2</sup>  The result is a new commit `C8`:

```
  C2---M3---C4---C5---C8  <-- some (HEAD)
 /    /
C1---C3---C6---C7  <-- master
```

which very likely has the *content* that you want: `C1` as snapshot plus `C2` as changeset to get `C2` as content, plus `M3` vs `C2` as changeset to get `M3` as content (but then eventually *minus* `M3` vs `C2` as changeset at the end), and so on.  Since `C8` *un-does* what `M3` did, `C8` should have the desired content.

At this point you can, if you like, `git reset --soft <hash-of-C1>`, leaving the index and work-tree set up the way you wanted, and then run `git commit` to create commit `C9`:

```
  C2---M3---C4---C5---C8
 /    /
C1---C3---C6---C7  <-- master
 \
  C9  <-------------- some (HEAD)
```

With no *name* by which to find them, all the commits along the top row of the graph here become invisible, and after 30 days or so, Git really removes them when it runs its garbage collector.

---

<sup>1</sup>In particular, if we use `git revert <hash-of-C3>`, we might revert too much.  That's why we `git revert -m 1 <hash-of-M3>` here.

<sup>2</sup>This assumes the first parent of `M3` is in fact `C2`.  In any normal commit growth process, it will be, but it's worth double-checking.